# Can I have (half) my bounty back?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What happens if I set up a bounty on a question, answer it myself and get at least 2 upvotes?
Do I get half my bounty back? Does it matter if it was my own question or someone else's?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the [source for information for all things bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

In particular: as noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802) t is not possible to award a bounty to one's own answer. The bounty will evaporate and the answer will display as having been awarded a bounty worth +0 reputation.