# Bounty on Question

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, self-answer

I had asked a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange which I placed a bounty on and received no answers except my own answer. 
See link: [$L(G)' \cap B \rtimes G = G^B$ if G ICC. If G is not ICC then $L(G)' \cap B \rtimes G = B^G \overline{\otimes} L(FC_G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250079/lg-cap-b-rtimes-g-gb-if-g-icc-if-g-is-not-icc-then-lg-cap-b-rti)

As you can see I received the most upvotes, so will I be awarded my own bounty?

Comment: See also: [Can I have (half) my bounty back?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3732)

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

See from here [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

> **Can I award a bounty to my own answer?**
>
> No. This used to be possible, but it has been disabled. The user would
>   not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as +0,
>   “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias, when you offer a bounty there is no way of getting your rep back.

Comment: No robbery. The bounty is just a fee you paid to get the question more air time. Not at all unlike paying your local newspaper to advertise your product/service. May be some voters would not have checked out the question and not voted at all without the bounty? Just be a good sport and award the bounty to someone else. At least they will remember :-)

Comment: No one else answered my question..... that is my issue or else I would award it...